# Ejecutar funcion de PHP desde C#

Tags: php, c#, api, restful

Tengo una API REST con una funcion que me retorna un numero(folio para mi) y le suma 1 y asi sucesivamente, si yo ejecuto esa funcion desde Postam mediante la URL de la API me devuelve lo que quiero, hasta aqui todo muy bien. Ahora como mando ejecutar esa funcion desde c#?, no le pasaria parametros solo quiero que me ejecute la funcion y la respuesta devuelta es un json_encode(mensaje).
Tengo entendido que se puede hacer con webclient downloadstring(url api) pero no me devuelve el json, solo me devuelve null.
Alguna ayuda seria bienvenida.
Desde ya gracias.

Aqui el codigo en PHP:

```
else if($_GET['url'] == "folio")
{
  $respuesta = Clientes::ObtenerFolio();
  $contenedor = array();
  if($respuesta)
  {
    $contenedor["resultado"]="OK";
    $contenedor["datos"]= $respuesta;
    echo json_encode($contenedor);
  }
  else
  {
    echo json_encode(array(
        "resultado" => 'NONE',
        "mensaje" =>'No se pudo asignar folio al cliente'
    ));
  }
```

Este es de C# winforms:

```
try
{
  string responsebody;

  HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await cliente.GetAsync("http://www.mipagina.mx/WebService/folio");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  dynamic datosdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody);
  string mjsserver = datosdes.resultado;
  string msjservernot = datosdes.datos;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: deberia ver algo de codigo... pero intuyo que estas utilizando webclient y no httpcliente por tus comentarios, cambia el webclient por httpclient 
e intercambia tu downloadstring por : HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/Funcion", Parametro);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

Comment: ups... ese metodo es para postear un json, lo que quieres es bajarlo, para eso necesitas : var response = await HttpClientObject.GetStringAsync("/api/function");

Comment: Manny manito pon algo de código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: en PHP tengo esto: else if($_GET['url'] == "folio")
        {
            $respuesta = Clientes::ObtenerFolio();
            $contenedor = array();
            if($respuesta)
            {
                $contenedor["resultado"]="OK";
                $contenedor["datos"]= $respuesta;
                echo json_encode($contenedor);
            }
            else
            {
            echo json_encode(array("resultado" => 'NONE',"mensaje" =>'No se pudo asignar folio al cliente'));
            }
        }

Comment: en C# tengo esto: 
string responsebody;
                HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await cliente.GetAsync("http://www.mipagina.mx/WebService/folio");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic datosdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody);
                string mjsserver = datosdes.resultado;
                string msjservernot = datosdes.datos;

Comment: edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo el cuerpo de la pregunta y dale una indentación de 5 espacios para que sea detectado como codigo, aqui perdió todo formato

Comment: @Mike ya esta editado la pregunta principal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno gracias a los que comentaron, todo en C# era correcto, pero en PHP yo estaba recibiendo todo por `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` y esta claro que desde C# yo hago `GetAsync` pues nunca me hiba a retornar "algo", asi que hice un else if despues del `POST` asi `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"` y ahi dentro puse

```
if($_GET['url'] == "folio")
        {
            $respuesta = Clientes::ObtenerFolio();
            $contenedor = array();
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            if($respuesta)
            {
                $contenedor["resultado"]="OK";
                $contenedor["datos"]= $respuesta;
                echo json_encode($contenedor);
            }
            else
            {
            echo json_encode(array("resultado" => 'NONE',"mensaje" =>'No se pudo asignar folio al cliente'));
            }
        }
```

y esto me retorno el json ya nadamos lo deserializo en C# y listo.
    Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

esto : http://www.mipagina.mx/WebService/folio", te regresa algun resultado ?
si no funciona entonces tu rest endpoint esta mal

me suena a que lo que tendrás que hacer es algo así :

```
 http://www.mipagina.mx/WebService.php?url="folio"
```

Comment: que tal Mike ejecuto esto tal cual desde Postam y selecciono POST y si me retorna lo esperado,
 http://www.mipagina.mx/WebService/folio 
retorna: {"resultado":"OK","datos":{"Folio":"1"}}

Comment: me regresa esto: 
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

No se puede ejecutar el enlace de tiempo de ejecución en una referencia nula